# Backbone.js - Fetch() not being called from my router

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, asynchronous, fetch, jquery-deferred

I'll try and simplify this as much as possible..

My routes.js :

```
direct_message: function(member_id) {

  list.conversations(function(conversations) { 
    conversation_view.model = conversations.models[conversations.models.length - 1];
    conversation_view.render();
  });
```

Ok so `conversations()` is a function inside my list model that is has a convenient little fetch() method and a callback to it ( which is the method I'm passing into it ). It checks to see if things have been **fetched**, and if so, returns the callback with the fetched parameters.. As so :

```
conversations: function(callback) {
  var _callback = _.bind(function() { if(callback) callback(this._conversations); }, this);
  if(!this._conversations) {
    this._conversations = new app.collections.Conversations();
    this._conversations.url = this._url();
    app.events.on('pusher:conversation_started', this._conversation_started, this);
  }
  if(this._conversations._fetched) {
    _callback();
  } else {
    this._conversations.on('reset', _callback);
    if(!this._conversations._fetching) {
      this._conversations._fetching = true;
      this._conversations.fetch({
        success: function(c) { c._fetched = true; },
        error: function(c) { c._fetching = false; }
      });
    }
  }
  return this._conversations;
},
```

Phew! I hope I didn't lose you yet. So this cascaded all fine and proper for awhile. But now, for some reason, when I perform that method within my `routes.js`, it returns back as `undefined`.

The reason I think this is happening is because that fetch request is asynchronous. So the return is coming back correctly, but the `return` statement is called before the data comes back. So all the other calls to `conversation()` actually return correctly except for the first one which initialized it.

Then I was thinking, let me just add `async: false` to the fetch() call, but when I do this, for some reason the later calls come back `undefined`. Is there *anything* else I can do? Maybe something else I should be looking at? Possibly some way to incorporate $.deferred objects in this?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you shouldn't `return this._conversations` but always access `this._conversations` via a callback, regardless of whether the fetch has already occurred or not.

You can do this by changing fetch's success handler to read :-

```
success: function(c) {
    c._fetched = true;
    _callback();
},
```

and (unless you absolutely need it) deleting the line :-

```
return this._conversations;
```

This will at least ensure that, when a callback is passed, you get the same behaviour on first and subsequent calls.

Comment: Wow I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks so much Beetroot-Beetroot! ( I'm actually drinking a beet right now )

Comment: "drinking a beet" - strangely that is something I've never done - too much like cannibalism I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

In Backbone 1.1 `fetch()` no longer triggers `reset` event by default.  Either pass `reset: true` to `fetch()` call or (recommended), listen to `sync` event instead.